# Use array destructuring instead of slice

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

How do I use array `destructuring` instead of `Array.slice()`

Are there any benefits instead of slicing it?

```
transposed[idx] = [ 'Calendar Name', 'Standard' ]

acc.name = transposed[idx].slice(1)[0]; // => 'Standard'
```

Comment: what is `transposed`, `idx`?

Answer (score 1):

You could destruct the array with `[arg1,arg2]`

```js
const [a,b] = [ 'Calendar Name', 'Standard' ]

console.log(a,b)
```

for yours

```
   const [calName,standard] = transposed[idx]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const [first,second] = transposed[idx];
// first = 'Calendar Name'
// second = 'Standard'
```

Honestly, the way to do this is `transposed[idx][1]`, not array destructuring or slice **if all you want is the value `Standard`**, if you're just going to drop `Calendar Name` on the floor anyway and not use it

Comment: ignoring the first item (`const [,second] = transposed[idx];`) would also work.

Comment: @marzelin - very nice! It sure does. Personally, I find that hard on the eyes. Feels like the OP is doing a learning assignment or getting poor code review feedback to be honest - KISS.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer after editing the question**

```js
const arr = ["Calendar Name", "Standard"];

const [first, second] = arr;
console.log(first, second);
```

**Answer before editing the question.**

```js
const arr = [
  ["Calendar Name", "Standard"],
  ["Valid From", 44197],
  ["Valid To", 44561],
  ["Use Holidays", "yes"],
  [
    "Working Day",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
    "Sunday",
  ],
  [
    "Start",
    0.3333333333333333,
    0.3333333333333333,
    0.3333333333333333,
    0.3333333333333333,
    0.3333333333333333,
    "-",
    "-",
  ],
  [
    "End",
    0.8333333333333334,
    0.8333333333333334,
    0.8333333333333334,
    0.8333333333333334,
    0.8333333333333334,
    "-",
    "-",
  ],
];

const [[first, second]] = arr;
console.log(first, second);
```